# Why would RDP into a machine's local admin be blocked by NLA

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server, windows-domain

My team and I were recently doing some maintenance on a domain joined server. We ended up having to remove the server from the domain and rejoining it. After completing the process we verified that we could log into the machine with domain and local admin credentials. Though after around 15mins the machine dropped off the domain and we were able to see it on one of our domain controllers but not the other. After forcing a replication the machine completely fell off the domain. When we tried to log into the machine using domain credentials we were obviously met with an NLA authentication error because the server couldn't communicate with the domain controller. This was expected...but what wasn't was when we tried to local administrator we were greeted with the same NLA Authentication error. I've never experienced this before as the local administrator should still be able to access despite whether the server can communicate with the domain. The following documentation backs this up:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/cannot-connect-rdp-azure-vm

Would anybody be able to think of a reason why the NLA would be blocking a local administrator from logging in?

Comment: Have you tried logging on locally? I wonder if the machine might spit out an error about the trust relationship being broken.

Comment: Unfortunately this machine lived in the cloud so getting local access is impossible. We believe the Domain Controller messed something up horribly when trying to pull it off the domain.